# really strange bug with HTML5 video

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, video

I am doing this under chrome, and what i am doing is as follows

```
var somevideo= document.querySelector('#video-tag');
```

then i use that to add a source though appendChild it appends it to the

```
somevideo.parentNode.parentNode
```

without me ever defining parent Node in the script.
Anything i try to do with play or pause it says its an HTML element, yet if i try to console some video it shows up with.

```
<video id="somevideo"></video>
```

any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

took asking till i figured it out, in a separate function i needed to target the parent, it was very removed from it so i never thought to look, but it made all other methods afterwards target that parent.

Comment: Please add more explanation as to how you solved the problem. That will help others, and possibly earn you some reputation if people upvote.